# Simplifying expression: $1 - \frac{1}{ (1 + a) / (1 - a)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Correct Answer is $a$

My attempt:

$$1 - \frac{1}{ (1 + a) / (1 - a)}= 1 - \frac{1 - a}{1 + a}  $$

multiply $(1 + a)$ on num and dem for the first term.

$$=\frac{1 + a}{1 + a} - \frac{1 - a}{1 + a}$$

combine and subtract.

$$=\frac{2a}{1 + a}$$

How does this simplify to $a$?

Comment: You should format your questions using MathJax if you want a quick answer :)

Comment: I don't know why anyone would think the answer is $a$, but you've correctly solved the problem as you've stated it.

Comment: Thanks. The solution manual just stated the answer without a solution.

Answer (score 3):

$$1 - {1\over  {1 + a\over 1 - a}}  = 1-{1-a\over 1+a} ={1+a\over 1+a}- {1-a\over 1+a} = {2a\over 1+a}$$

so it does not. Your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 2):

$$1 - \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1 + a}{1 - a}} = 1 - \dfrac{1 - a}{1 + a} = \dfrac{1 + a}{1 + a} - \dfrac{1 - a}{1 + a} = \dfrac{(1 + a) - (1 - a)}{1 + a} = \dfrac{2a}{1 + a} \ne a;$$

I agree with user582949; our OP is right at the answer he/she was given is wrong.